# Image resized when using NSUrl

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm working on an OSX app and I'm trying to get an image from a NSUrl. It works well, but with some images (not every image), the size is not good.

For example, I'm trying to get a 1600 * 1200 image from the NSUrl, but when I NSlog the value I get the result is 384 * 288, so the quality is decreased.
But this bug is not on every images.

I have tried this with PNG and JPG, the result is the same, some are resized, some are not.

I dont want the image to be resized because the quality is my main concern.

Here's my code :

```
 - (IBAction)loadImageAction:(id)sender {
    NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"jpg",@"png", nil];
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
    [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];

    NSInteger clicked = [panel runModal];
    if (clicked == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        for (NSURL *url in [panel URLs]) {
            NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            NSLog(@"IMAGE FROM URL : image.width = %f, image.height = %f", img.size.width, img.size.height);
            if (img != nil) {
                [_imageView setImage:img]; // just a NSImageView to display the image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the size of your `_imageView` control ?

Comment: It's 329 * 169, but I've tried to resize it and it doesnt make any difference. Moreover, I print the value of `img` before seting it to `_imageView` and the problem is already here.

Comment: Your image has a resolution 300 dpi. You can see it from NSLog( @"img is %@", image);  There is no bug! The resolution is defined as dpiX = 72.0*[image pixlesWide] / [image size].width; (same for y). And now: where is your problem?

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your explanation @HeinrichGiesen, that was the problem. I didnt know how it works.

Comment: @Zakaria, your link allowed me to find the solution, thank you.